# Android - how do I switch a hardcoded 2 column layout to a dynamic one that handles screen width?

Tags: android, android-layout

I currently have this 2-column layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:paddingTop="4dip"
     android:paddingBottom="6dip"
     android:paddingLeft="4dip"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"

     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal">

     <TextView android:id="@+id/TRAIN_CELL"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textSize="16sp"
         android:layout_weight="11"/>

     <TextView android:id="@+id/TO_CELL"
         android:layout_width="0dip"
         android:textSize="20sp"
         android:textStyle="bold" 
         android:gravity="center"
         android:textColor="@color/light_best_blue"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
         android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

On the left is text and on the right is this character ">" signaling to the users that it can be pressed.  What I did not is hardcode the list with pixel numbers, but is there a way to make it more dynamic and work off screen percentages?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I tried the above layout and it looks strange with the ">" character is displayed as the next character right after the text on the left. Any idea why that happens?

Comment: @Ice Box I thought there are just certain fields that are different. No?

Comment: Set `layout_width="0dp"` for both and use `layout_weight` to control width. For example, your current layout would use weight `11` for the text, and weight `1` for the arrow.